# Как запретить ввод несколько нулей подряд в текстовое поле ввода?

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Как запретить ввод в текстовое поле несколько нулей одновременно, чтобы можно было вводить только числа с плавающей запятой, например, 0,5 и целые числа 0, 10, 100 и т.д. в Jquery?

```js
        function setStrictNumberPattern() {
            let inp = document.querySelectorAll('.area');
            for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
                let lastVal = "";
                inp[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
                    if (!this.value) return (lastVal = "");
                    if ((/^\d+\d*[,]?\d*$/).test(this.value)) {
                        lastVal = this.value;
                    } else {
                        this.value = lastVal;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Может, `/^(?!0[^,])\d+(?:,\d+)?$/`?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, в этом случае числа 0,5, 0,9 не вводятся, а нужно чтобы вводились

Comment: Тогда `^(?!0+(?:[1-9]|$)|0{2,},)\d+(?:,\d+)?$` - https://regex101.com/r/n6N85U/3

Comment: По-моему, `^(?!0[^,])\d+(?:,\d+)?$` [работает, как надо](https://regex101.com/r/n6N85U/6).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(([1-9]\d*)|0)(.\d+)?$
```

- `^(([1-9]\d*)|0)` вначале ожидаем не 0 и сколько угодно цифр или только один ноль
- `(.\d+)?` а потом может идти точка и хотя бы одна цифра

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/JCOc6T/1)

Регулярка будет пропускать числа с завершающим нулем `0.0`, `9.780`. Если это не нужно, то нужно часть `(.\d+)?` заменить на `(.\d*[1-9])?`